# Creating a jagged array out of arrays in a static class in C# gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, arrays, static

I've created a static class for palettes and have many static palettes. I want to create a jagged array out of them so they are easier to access.

This doesn't work, if I use it from another class with `Palette.PaletteList[0][0]` it will give a NullReferenceException.

```
public static class Palette
{
    public static UInt32[][] PaletteList = new UInt32[][] {
    GreyscaleBGRA , GreyscaleInvertedBGRA, FLIRIronBGRA,
    BlackbodyBGRA, SpectrumBGRA, SpectralBGRA, EarthBGRA,
    BlackToBlueBGRA, BlueToBlackBGRA, WhiteToBlueBGRA,
    BlueToWhiteBGRA};
    .
    .
    .
```

Here's what an palette array looks like:

```
public static readonly UInt32[] GreyscaleBGRA =  { 0x000000FF,
0x010101FF, 0x020202FF, 0x030303FF, 0x040404FF, 0x050505FF,
0x060606FF, 0x070707FF, 0x080808FF, 0x090909FF, 0x0A0A0AFF,
0x0B0B0BFF, 0x0C0C0CFF,.............
```

If I put in the raw data it works:

```
public static UInt32[][] PaletteList = new UInt32[][] { new UInt32[] {
0x000000FF, 0x010101FF, 0x020202FF, 0x030303FF, 0x040404FF,
0x050505FF, 0x060606FF, 0x070707FF, 0x080808FF, 0x090909FF,
0x0A0A0AFF, 0x0B0B0BFF, ...........
```

If I create the jagged array in another class it works:

```
UInt32[][] PaletteList = new UInt32[][] { Palette.GreyscaleBGRA,
Palette.GreyscaleInvertedBGRA, Palette.FLIRIronBGRA,
Palette.BlackbodyBGRA, Palette.SpectrumBGRA, Palette.SpectralBGRA,
Palette.EarthBGRA, Palette.BlackToBlueBGRA, Palette.BlueToBlackBGRA,
Palette.WhiteToBlueBGRA, Palette.BlueToWhiteBGRA, Palette.BlackToGreenBGRA };
```

I know how to make it work but I don't want to put the raw data into the jagged array, it becomes unvieldy. Are the palette arrays not initialized and populated before the jagged array is created in the static class? Is it possible to make it work in a static class?
I'm hoping that there is an easy fix for this that I just haven't noticed or know about.

Comment: Thanks for the info shingo. Learned something new today about static classes. Never new that the order static fields are of importance.